# Conversion Error

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

can someone please tell me why i am getting the following error, when i run through my code, im not to sure if its a problem with my sql statement as this seems to be ok, but i added it below so that i can get a second opinion

"Conversion failed when converting date/time from character string"

```
public static int GetConveyorProductionCount(string machineNameV, string StartTimeV, string EndTimeV)
    {

        try
        {
            int count;

            SqlParameter param01 = new SqlParameter("@param01", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
            param01.Value = machineNameV;

            SqlParameter param02 = new SqlParameter("@param02", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
            param02.Value = StartTimeV;

            SqlParameter param03 = new SqlParameter("@param03", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
            param03.Value = EndTimeV;

            SqlCommand getConveyorProductionSC = new SqlCommand("SELECT cast([" + machineNameV + "] as int) FROM VWCONVEYORPRODUCTION WHERE([DA_TE] BETWEEN @param02 AND @param03)", myConnection);

            getConveyorProductionSC.Parameters.Add(param01);
            getConveyorProductionSC.Parameters.Add(param02);
            getConveyorProductionSC.Parameters.Add(param03);

            myConnection.Open();
            object result = getConveyorProductionSC.ExecuteScalar();
            myConnection.Close();

            if (result == DBNull.Value)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            }

            return count;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error retrieving the Conveyor production count. Error: " + e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: What are the values of StartTimeV and EndTimeV

Comment: On which line did you get error?

Comment: the error"Conversion failed when converting date/time from character string" tells you that you are passing a datetime as string, and the conversion fails....

Comment: At what line are you getting this error? Are you sure you are passing GetConveyorProductionCount() 3 strings or are you passing it a DateTime object? Also in your VWCONVEYORPRODUCTION table in the db, id the DA_TE column a varchar or a date type?

Comment: @Andrii Kalyuiituk i get the error on this line " object result = getConveyorProductionSC.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: @astander the values are set to what ever date and time it is now

Comment: Yeah like what date format fits in Varchar(5)...

Comment: Why don't you pass the dates as `DateTime` parameters (both to the method and to the `SqlCommand` instead?

Answer (score 5):

Well aside from the large amount of other problems with this code

```
SqlParameter param02 = new SqlParameter("@param02", SqlDbType.DateTime);
param02.Value = StartTimeV;
SqlParameter param03 = new SqlParameter("@param03", SqlDbType.DateTime);
param03.Value = EndTimeV;
```

Would be a good start
Assuming of course the DA_TE column in the table is a datetime?
Of course you need to pass them in as DateTimes as well

I do commend you for using parameterised queries though.

If it was me my code would look something like

```
public static int GetConveyorProductionCount(string machineNameV, DateTime StartTimeV, DateTime EndTimeV)
{
  {
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
  {
    connection.Open();
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SELECT cast([{0}] as int) FROM VWCONVEYORPRODUCTION WHERE([DA_TE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)", machineNameV), connection);            
    {
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate",StartTimeV);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate",EndTimeV);
      object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
      if (result == DBNull.Value)
      {
        return 0;
      }
      else
      {
        return (Int32)result;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anything you create one the fly that implements IDisposable put inside a using block.

Don't unless you are doing explicit transactions, or have connection caching turned off persist Ado.Net db connections.

Pass DateTimes as DateTimes

Give your variables decent names, param02 doesn't mean anything, and count was misleading.

Don't create stuff before you need it

The thing you did with exception
I personally wouldn't bother trapping in this code, especially simply to throw it again, after throwing all the useful details about the exception away.

If you want to do that, define a CustomException, then do
throw new MyCustomException("Error retrieving the Conveyor production count.",e);

That way we you'll be able to trap this specific exception if you need to, but you'll have the entire exception chain and all the stack traces.

Last but not least treat all coding examples including mine, as though they were constructed by the village idiot's thick cousin. :D

Answer (score 1):

My theory would be that the strings passed as DateTime is not in the correct format.

Have a look at the example below

[SQL Fiddle DEMO of working value](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4965/0)

[SQL Fiddle DEMO of broken value](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4966)

The second example using *01 Ja 2012* (note the **Ja** and not **Jan**) produces the errror message

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your issue is that DA_TE column in your VWCONVEYORPRODUCTION table is a sql date type. So this means your parameters should also be date types.

```
public static int GetConveyorProductionCount(string machineNameV, DateTime StartTimeV, DateTime EndTimeV)
    {
    enter code here
        try
        {
            int count;

            SqlParameter param01 = new SqlParameter("@param01", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
            param01.Value = machineNameV;

            SqlParameter param02 = new SqlParameter("@param02", SqlDbType.date);
            param02.Value = StartTimeV;

            SqlParameter param03 = new SqlParameter("@param03", SqlDbType.date);
            param03.Value = EndTimeV;

            SqlCommand getConveyorProductionSC = new SqlCommand("SELECT cast([" + machineNameV + "] as int) FROM VWCONVEYORPRODUCTION WHERE([DA_TE] BETWEEN @param02 AND @param03)", myConnection);

            getConveyorProductionSC.Parameters.Add(param01);
            getConveyorProductionSC.Parameters.Add(param02);
            getConveyorProductionSC.Parameters.Add(param03);

            myConnection.Open();
            object result = getConveyorProductionSC.ExecuteScalar();
            myConnection.Close();

            if (result == DBNull.Value)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            }

            return count;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error retrieving the Conveyor production count. Error: " + e.Message);
        }
```

Use `DateTime.ParseExact()` if you need to convert strings to DateTimes before calling this function.